# Find path from one city to other and then reverse with no city revisited

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I found a problem on Algorithms on [usaco](http://ace.delos.com/), I cannot link to real problem as it requires authentication so pasting it.

> You have just won a contest where the prize is a free vacation in Canada. You must travel via air, and the cities are ordered from east to west. In addition, according to the rules, you must start at the further city west, travel only east until you reach the furthest city east, and then fly only west until you reach your starting location. In addition, you may visit no city more than once (except the starting city, of course).
>
> Given the order of the cities, with the flights that can be done (you can only fly between certain cities, and just because you can fly from city A to city B does not mean you can fly the other direction), calculate the maximum number of cities you can visit.

This is part of tutorial text on dynamic programming. There is suggestion for solution also given in the tutorial.

> Imagine having two travelers who start in the western most city. The travelers take turns traveling east, where the next traveler to move is always the western-most, but the travelers may never be at the same city, unless it is either the first or the last city. However, one of the traveler is only allowed to make "reverse flights," where he can travel from city A to city B if and only if there is a flight from city B to city A.
>
> It's not too difficult to see that the paths of the two travelers can be combined to create a round-trip, by taking the normal traveler's path to the eastern-most city, and then taking the reverse of the other traveler's path back to the western-most city. Also, when traveler x is moved, you know that the traveler y has not yet visited any city east of traveler x except the city traveler y is current at, as otherwise traveler y must have moved once while x was west of y.

As far as I understood the solution, I think that the solution can be done by keeping a one dimensional table for outgoing city in forward direction and a table for outgoing city in reverse direction.
eg. If I have 5 cities, A,B...E orientated in required direction and directed graph between cities is A is starting city and E is the destination.

```
   A | B | C | D | E
A  0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0
B  0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0
C  1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1
D  0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1
E  0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0
```

I am keeping two tables one for outgoing city I will fill it by initializing first city as 1 ie. number of maximum cities visited and then for each next entry scan all the previous cities from which a path exists to the current city and then choose maximum, doing the same for reverse traveler.

```
table[i] = Max(j=i to 0) (table[j])
```

I will have maximum at the destination city, but this doesn't guarantee that any city is not repeated. If I keep one more entry in the array field along with maximum number I won't be able to switch it from forward to reverse. I am learning dynamic programming so may be I did not get correct idea.
This is the table which I constructed for the graph

```
A | B | C | D | E
1 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 4
1 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 3
```

so will take maximum from both. Please provide directions/hints so that I can proceed in right direction.

PS. this is not a homework question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach with the two tables models the state for each traveler independently, as the number of cities already visited, combined with the location where that traveler is currently staying. As you found out yourself, that won't prevent visiting a city twice.

Instead, I'd use three elements to model state: the city where one traveler is currently located, the city where the other is located, and the number of cities they have visited in total, i.e. the sum of their individual counts. So you'd have a single 2d table, instead of your two 1d tables. Cell (*f*, *r*) would contain the best known number of total cities visited when the forward traveler is in city *f* and the reverse traveler is in city *r*.

You'd probably iterate over these states in order of their minimal element. That means you'll next expand a state which you have not expanded yet, and where the smaller of these two numbers is minimal among all unexpanded states. If in that state, *f* < *r*, then you'd use it to update states (*f'*, *r*) with *f'* > *r*, if there is a flight from *f* to *f'*. On the other hand, if *r* < *f* you update (*f*, *r'*) with *r'* > *f* and a flight from *r'* to *r*.

In pseudocode:

```
first = (f: 0, r: 0)  # tuple with two members, called f and r
todo = set { first }  # a set with a tuple as its only element
visited = a map from tuples to integers, unset values defaulting to 0
visited[first] = 1
while todo is not empty:
  best = ∞
  cur = null
  for t in todo:
    if min(t.f, t.r) < best:
      best = min(t.f, t.r)
      cur = t
  todo.remove(cur)
  if (cur.f < cur.r):
    for f' in cities where flights from f arrive:
      next = (f: f', r: cur.r)  # keep r but use f' as the new f
      todo.add(next)            # will do nothing if it already is in the set
      visited[next] = max(visited[next], visited[cur] + 1)
  else:
    for r' in cities where flights to r depart:
      next = (f: cur.f, r: r')
      todo.add(next)
      visited[next] = max(visited[next], visited[cur] + 1)
best = 0
for cur in keys of visited:
  if best < visited[cur]:
    if there is a flight from cur.f to cur.r: # can close the tour
      best = visited[cur]
return best
```

Comment: How would that third table prevent the revisiting of a city?

Comment: @gaurav: Not a third table, but instead a single 2d table instead of your two 1d tables. I'll elaborate on that in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but sorry i am unable to understand the solution, what is the minimal element you are talking about? Could you give some pseudo-code or give me recursion so that I could understand the gist?

Comment: @gaurav, I added some pseudocode, I hope it is understandable. The "minimal element" of a state is simply the westernmost of the two travelers, no matter which one that is. I denoted that `min(t.f, t.r)` in my pseudocode.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, now I understood the meaning.